# Newark to Oslo to Bergen: Where do I go through Customs & Immigration?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, oslo, sas

I've got an itinerary coming up where I'll be flying SAS from Newark, New Jersey to Oslo, Norway, followed by a connecting flight to Bergen. Both flights are part of the same booking. It's only just occurred to me that I've never done this particular combination before, where an International flight is followed by a Domestic.

Does anyone know how Customs & Immigration will work for this? Will I be going through Immigration in Oslo before transferring to the Domestic terminal, or does that need to wait until Bergen? If I'm going through Customs in Oslo, do I need to claim my bags and recheck, or can I check them straight through to Bergen, since it's the same itinerary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oslo Airport [DOMESTIC TRANSFER](https://avinor.no/en/airport/oslo-airport/plan-your-trip/transfer/domestic-transfer)

> All passengers travelling with Norwegian, **SAS** or Widerøe, from international to domestic, should use **Domestic Transfer**.
>
> Passengers must pass through customs at gate D2 (yellow area) and then enter the domestic departure terminal. **Your baggage will be transferred directly to the next flight as long as it has been marked with your final destination and does not contain animals or weapons.**
>
> The service is only valid for passengers who have a “through ticket”. This means **your baggage tag is marked with your final destination**, and not “OSL”, when you check in abroad.

From this it looks as if you **do not need** to collect your bags for a customs check

- if they don't like something, they will probably be waiting for you in Bergen.

---

Overview Map of Olso Airport

[image]

Immigration Control (Passport) seems to be done

- between Areas F and E (see Departure pdf) assumtions:

  - International incoming flights that need Passport controls arrrive at F
  - others International at E and D
- Domestic flights are the Areas A, B and C

  - one of these will be the flight to Bergen

The main building (below/south of Areas A, E and F) are security controls to enter these areas from the outside.

> **Domestic Transfer step by step**
>
> - Follow the signs marked “Transfer” after leaving the aircraft.
> - Make your way to Domestic Transfer near gate D2 – the yellow area.
> - Shop your tax free goods before entering customs.
> - After passing through customs, check the information for your connecting flight and then follow the signs to your departure gate.

---

The Customs page contains links to 2 Airport maps as pdf

- [Detailed Departures](https://avinor.no/globalassets/_oslo-lufthavn/avgang-departures-rev_juni2019.pdf)
- [Detailed Arrivals](https://avinor.no/globalassets/_oslo-lufthavn/ankomst-arrivals-2018-3.pdf)